# Problem with cmake in Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, compiler-errors

I am working on a new project in Visual Studio 2022 Community. I'm using cmake and am completely new to this, so I'm not sure where to start. I've tried every possible correction I have found online and am unable to determine the problem. I have had issues with generating the cmake cache. The errors have ranged from unable to locate the cl.exe or rc.exe files, to path issues and everything in between. I have added folder locations to the path. Cmake is not able to compile a simple test program.

I am completely new to coding and am doing this as a side project, so my knowledge is limited. I would appreciate any help.

I am trying to debug a program I have written in C++. The program cannot run as I get an error that cmake generation failed. Here is the output when I attempt to debug:

```
    CMake generation started for configuration: 'x64-debug'.
1> Environment settings:
1>     asl.log=Destination=file
1>     CommandPromptType=Native
1>     DevEnvDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\
1>     ExtensionSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs
1>     EXTERNAL_INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um
1>     Framework40Version=v4.0
1>     FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
1>     FrameworkDir64=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
1>     FrameworkVersion=v4.0.30319
1>     FrameworkVersion64=v4.0.30319
1>     FSHARPINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools
1>     INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include
1>     LIB=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib
1>     LIBPATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.22621.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.22621.0;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
1>     NETFXSDKDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\
1>     Path=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Team Tools\DiagnosticsHub\Collector;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\;C:\Program Files\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python311\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.1\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Python311;C:\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\Documents\Xoptfoil\bin\win64;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts\;"$env:Path = C:\gtk\bin; + $env:Path";"$env:LIB = C:\gtk\lib; + $env:LIB";"$env:INCLUDE = C:\gtk\include;C:\gtk\include\cairo;C:\gtk\include\glib-2.0;C:\gtk\include\gobject-introspection-1.0;C:\gtk\lib\glib-2.0\include; + $env:INCLUDE";c:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\.local\bin;C:\gtk-build\gtk\x64\release\bin;c:\users\robert petrowsky\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\Hostx64\x64;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\vcpkg
1>     PROMPT=$P$G
1>     UCRTVersion=10.0.22621.0
1>     UniversalCRTSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
1>     VCIDEInstallDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\
1>     VCINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\
1>     VCPKG_ROOT=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\vcpkg
1>     VCToolsInstallDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\
1>     VCToolsRedistDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.38.33135\
1>     VCToolsVersion=14.39.33519
1>     VS170COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\
1>     VSCMD_ARG_app_plat=Desktop
1>     VSCMD_ARG_HOST_ARCH=x64
1>     VSCMD_ARG_no_logo=1
1>     VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH=x64
1>     VSCMD_DEBUG=5 
1>     VSCMD_VER=17.9.1
1>     VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\
1>     WindowsLibPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.22621.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.22621.0
1>     WindowsSdkBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\
1>     WindowsSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
1>     WindowsSDKLibVersion=10.0.22621.0\
1>     WindowsSdkVerBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\
1>     WindowsSDKVersion=10.0.22621.0\
1>     WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\
1>     WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\
1>     __DOTNET_ADD_64BIT=1
1>     __DOTNET_PREFERRED_BITNESS=64
1>     __VSCMD_PREINIT_INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include
1>     __VSCMD_PREINIT_PATH=C:\Program Files\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python311\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.1\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Python311;C:\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\Documents\Xoptfoil\bin\win64;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts\;"$env:Path = C:\gtk\bin; + $env:Path";"$env:LIB = C:\gtk\lib; + $env:LIB";"$env:INCLUDE = C:\gtk\include;C:\gtk\include\cairo;C:\gtk\include\glib-2.0;C:\gtk\include\gobject-introspection-1.0;C:\gtk\lib\glib-2.0\include; + $env:INCLUDE";c:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\.local\bin;C:\gtk-build\gtk\x64\release\bin;c:\users\robert petrowsky\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\Hostx64\x64;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
1>     OneDriveConsumer=C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\OneDrive
1>     ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
1>     ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
1>     ChocolateyInstall=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey
1>     PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
1>     TMP=C:\Users\ROBERT~1\AppData\Local\Temp
1>     PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
1>     Path=C:\Program Files\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python311\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.1\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Python311;C:\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\Documents\Xoptfoil\bin\win64;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts\;"$env:Path = C:\gtk\bin; + $env:Path";"$env:LIB = C:\gtk\lib; + $env:LIB";"$env:INCLUDE = C:\gtk\include;C:\gtk\include\cairo;C:\gtk\include\glib-2.0;C:\gtk\include\gobject-introspection-1.0;C:\gtk\lib\glib-2.0\include; + $env:INCLUDE";c:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\.local\bin;C:\gtk-build\gtk\x64\release\bin;c:\users\robert petrowsky\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\Hostx64\x64;C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
1>     NVCUDASAMPLES10_1_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v10.1
1>     PkgDefApplicationConfigFile=C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_4e545d98\devenv.exe.config
1>     USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky
1>     configsetroot=C:\WINDOWS\ConfigSetRoot
1>     PROCESSOR_REVISION=9e0a
1>     ChocolateyLastPathUpdate=133271270339164809
1>     FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer
1>     FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default
1>     LOGONSERVER=\\MSI
1>     EFC_11492=1
1>     USERNAME=Robert Petrowsky
1>     SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
1>     TEMP=C:\Users\ROBERT~1\AppData\Local\Temp
1>     MSMPI_BIN=C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\
1>     OneDrive=C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\OneDrive
1>     ServiceHubLogSessionKey=EE5612F1
1>     NVCUDASAMPLES_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v10.1
1>     NVTOOLSEXT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
1>     VisualStudioDir=C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\Documents\Visual Studio 2022
1>     VSSKUEDITION=Community
1>     ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
1>     VS_Perf_Session_GCHeapCount=2
1>     VSAPPIDDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\
1>     HOMEPATH=\Users\Robert Petrowsky
1>     COMPUTERNAME=MSI
1>     ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
1>     CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
1>     VsPerMonitorDpiAwarenessEnabled.23204=TRUE
1>     ThreadedWaitDialogDpiContext=-4
1>     GCExpConfigUsedInSession=3
1>     SignInWithHomeTenantOnly=False
1>     SESSIONNAME=Console
1>     CUDA_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1
1>     DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
1>     HOMEDRIVE=C:
1>     windir=C:\WINDOWS
1>     SystemDrive=C:
1>     NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=12
1>     OS=Windows_NT
1>     ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN=1
1>     ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
1>     ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
1>     CUDA_PATH_V10_1=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1
1>     USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=MSI
1>     PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
1>     VSLANG=1033
1>     CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
1>     PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
1>     APPDATA=C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\AppData\Roaming
1>     USERDOMAIN=MSI
1>     PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
1>     asl.log=Destination=file
1>     LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\AppData\Local
1>     VisualStudioVersion=17.0
1>     VisualStudioEdition=Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
1>     CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
1>     PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
1>     VSAPPIDNAME=devenv.exe
1>     MSBuildLoadMicrosoftTargetsReadOnly=true
1> Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:/Users/Robert Petrowsky/source/repos/EasyCAD/EasyCAD/out/install/x64-debug"   -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\source\repos\EasyCAD\EasyCAD" 2>&1"
1> Working directory: C:/Users/Robert Petrowsky/source/repos/EasyCAD/EasyCAD/out/build/x64-debug
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done (0.1s)
1> [CMake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Robert Petrowsky/source/repos/EasyCAD/EasyCAD
1> Error: CMake file API response index file not found
```

Comment: In the current form of the question post we could only guess what is going on. Please, add to the question post the **exact error message** you got.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix using this Vscode extensions named C++ and CMake tools.
You can use quick start and debug using CMake tool extension and easy to apply with VsCode documentation. Link is here ....

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux